# Reference a variable via strings

Tags: javascript, protractor

**The Goal:** Iterate through the emails in my conf.js file, by evaluating a string as a variable.

I have tried using `eval(string name)`, `window[string name]`, and `this[string name]`.

I get errors like:

> unexpected number;
>
> each key must be a number of string; got undefined;

and so forth. What is the proper way to make a string run like a variable name? The issue is on the line second to last line in the for loop. Greatly appreciate your insight!

In my **conf.js** file, I have email addresses stored like the following:

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  params: {
    login: {
      username: '*********',
      password: '*********.'
    },
    website: {
      url: '*********',
    },
    testEmails: {
      // First address
      1: '*****@gmail.com',

      // Second address
      2: '*****@gmail.com',
    }
  }
}
```

**spec.js**

```
describe('Testing |', function() {

  var initialLink = ('https://').concat(browser.params.website.url);

  function loadPage(a) {
    browser.get(a);
  }

  function login(a, b) {
    element(by.model('login.userName')).clear().sendKeys(a);
    element(by.model('login.password')).clear().sendKeys(b);
    element(by.id('btnLogin')).click();
  }

  function send(a, b){
    element(by.id('btnCompose')).click();
    element(by.id('toCtrl_new')).sendKeys(a);
    element(by.id('subjectCtrl')).sendKeys(b);

    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
    element(by.id('btnCancel')).click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
  }

  it('should send emails', function() {
    loadPage(initialLink);
    login(browser.params.login.username, browser.params.login.password);
    element.all(by.repeater('module in ui.forUser')).get(3).click();

    for(var i = 1; i < 38; i++){
      var prefix = "browser.params.testEmails.";
      var complete = prefix.concat(i);
      var toWhom = eval(complete);
      send(toWhom, 'Testing');
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
for (key in browser.params.testEmails) {
  var toWhom = browser.params.testEmails[key];
  send(toWhom, 'Testing');
}
```

Comment: Wow, thats exactly what I needed, thanks Daniel! And if you could make a slight tweak, `testEmails[key]` should be `browser.params.testEmails[key]`.

Comment: No problem. Fixed that mistake